# Publishing URL through java application

Tags: java, facebook, url, publish

When posting a URL on the facebook wall, facebook get URL data and mounts a post with that information. I wonder how do I post to this format by sending an URL using Java, for example using the API restfb (http://restfb.com/) or using graph API or any other way to do this in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how does one do an HTTP Post using Java?

Comment: Your issue is a bit more complicated the the answer I posted is not applicable. I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do.

Comment: mre no,
See the image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/imglq.png
I would like to post this information (red circle) via Java.
I Could send the URL and facebook create post in this format or I send all data separately.
Example 1: send to facebook http://www.google.com as published in the Wall and the facebook posted as the red circle.
Or maybe:
Example 2: Using any format to send informations of the red circle to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var wallPost = {
            message : "Message in post",
            picture: URL_IMAGE,
            link: URL,
            name : POST_NAME,
            description: POST_DESCRIPTION
        };
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
                 console.log("Error to post");
          }
        });
```